# "All or none" policy for patch

Tags: diff, patch

I have patch file describing changes to multiple files to apply to the contents of a directory.

I would like to apply it *only* if all files can be patched successfully. If any one file cannot be patched, I would like to abort the process without modifying anything.

I could do a dry run first, parse the output and see if any hunk fails before applying it for real, but there must be a better way to do this.

Edit~ What I have is a series of folders with html/css, one for each of our users that they can modify. Unmodified folders are symlinks.
Changes made are usually very small, so when we release an update for the default code there should be no problem with applying a patch to update them most of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend doing a dry run.  You don't need to parse the output, just redirect it to /dev/null. The exit code tells you if it worked or not.

From the man page for `patch`, under "Diagnostics":

> patch's exit status is 0 if all hunks are applied  successfully,  1  if
>          some  hunks  cannot be applied, and 2 if there is more serious trouble.
>          When applying a set of patches in a loop it behooves you to check  this
>          exit  status  so  you  don't apply a later patch to a partially patched
>          file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).

That way, you can revert if the patch was not fully applied.

Comment: I guess I wasn't specific enough. That wouldn't work for my environment. I'll edit the question and provide more details.

Comment: @fonso - You were not specific at all and still are not. Why will that not work for your environment? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter for a newline and accidentally posted the comment.

Comment: @fonso - if you have information to add to the question, add it to the question, not to comments on an answer.

Comment: @fonso - even with your edit, I fail to see why revision control will not work.

Comment: @Oded I would have to have an instance of version control in each of our users' folder and pull/update for every new version. Also, I couldn't not to apply a specific change set if I wanted to.

Comment: @fonso - "each of our users' folder"... a bit more detail that could be used for context. Why not add that to the question as well?